# Plausible explanation for the ability to mechanically switch dominant hands

Tags: science-based, nanotechnology

Is there a plausible explanation for some sort of theoretical technology that manipulates the character's primary motor cortex into being ambidextrous?

For example, a character loses their right arm and cannot replace it with a robot one. But they're in a position where they don't have enough time to learn to switch dominant hands the old-fashioned way.

Would it be scientifically possible for some sort of nanotechnology to either manipulate their brain or their hand into "thinking" the character has always been left-handed so they can continue to work? I'm not completely sure how much of right/left-handedness is controlled by the mind and how much is muscle memory.

I realize there's a level of handwavium to this (and most other technorganics in science-fiction), but anything believably science-based would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a slick SF concept.  I wish it were a story so I could read what happens when someone applies the technology with ... different intentions.

Comment: I knew a person who could write equally with both hands at the same time. In fact, this person could start at a center line, one hand on each side of it, and write a sentence both ways, one an exact mirror image of the other. So yes it is plausible that it can be done. The instantaneous part, however, I am not sure of. I would posit that it  has to be from birth. That is why the hero is a hero.

Answer (score 4):

**It's all in the brain - mostly**

"[Muscle memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_memory#Muscle_memory_encoding)" is used to refer to the *brain's* programming of repeated use of particular actions.  Which means that if both limbs are fully symmetrical and equally muscled, then "all" that is required to use the non-master limb equally well is the ability for the brain to translate the outgoing signals so they can be sent to the other limb.

However, there are a few possible issues with this, depending on the skill that is in use.  For example:

1. Master eye - all people have a dominant eye when shooting, aiming etc.  When instructing with firearms, bows etc the first step is to determine the dominant eye, then train the shooter to use the hand that allows that eye to be used for aiming.  Unless you can re-wire the dominant eye at the same time, a person will not be as good at shooting with the other hand because of the eye rather than the limb.
2. Asymmetric equipment design - many firearms have some degree of asymmetry in their layout.  For example, the majority of semi-automatic / automatic firearms eject their brass to the right, the safety catch on the F88 Austeyr is engaged when pushed fully to the right and disengaged when pushed fully to the left.  (Yes, some handguns do have fully ambidextrous safeties and magazine releases but their is still some asymmetry.) Power tools also typically have asymmetric design - pushing a drill's selector all the way to one side makes the chuck spin clockwise, to the opposite side makes the chuck spin anticlockwise.  This means that even when using equipment that can be effectively operated one-handed, actions do not translate exactly - using the F88 Austeyr example above, a movement of the thumb is required to apply the safety catch and a movement of the index finger is required to go to "Instant" when the right hand is on the pistol grip, whereas the opposite action is required when using the left hand.
3. Asymmetric activities - As mentioned in one of the comments on the question, handwriting is an asymmetric activity.  Reversing it means that the person is writing in mirror image.  If the brain was rewired to do the same for gross muscle movements as well as fine muscle movements then it would make the non-master limb unusable - if aiming at a target that moved to the right then the arm would move to the left!  So any "rewiring" would need to ensure that it did not interfere with gross muscle movements.
4. Asymmetric muscle development.  Back when I was fencing with sabres, my right arm/wrist/hand became much stronger than my left.  The right limb was doing all the work during practice and bouts, while the left arm stayed locked behind my back out of harms way.  (The left arm gets to move quite a bit move in foil and epee, sabre creates the most exaggerated asymmetric development.)  Depending on the activity being undertaken it is possible that the muscles in the non-master hand will be less developed and that even if all the brain rewiring issues can be overcome that the user will be less capable due to inferior muscle development.

In summary - with sufficient skill at rewiring the brain, the non-master limb could be used effectively, but asymmetries in eyes, muscles, equipment and activity type may prevent equivalent competence from being instantly achieved.